# Edit a default latex/beamer theme to show section numbers

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, formatting, header-footer

I am using `beamer` to create a presentation. The theme I chose is `Singapore`. It has a nice header with section names and bullets for subsections.

What is the easiest way to modify the header so that it will also display the section number, not just the title?

Bonus question: how can I make the section numbers also appear in the table of contents?

So instead of:

> Introduction    Concepts    Realisation

it should be:

> 1. Introduction    2. Concepts   3. Realisation

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can redefine the `section in head/foot` and `section in head/foot shaded` templates to add `\insertsectionheadnumber`. For the bonus, you need to redefine section in toc to add `\inserttocsectionnumber`; an example illustrating these redefinitions:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}

\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{\hfill\insertsectionheadnumber.~\insertsectionhead}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{\color{structure!50}\hfill\insertsectionheadnumber.~\insertsectionhead}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\inserttocsectionnumber.~\inserttocsection}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\section{Test Section Two}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\section{Test Section Three}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting ToC showing the numbering both in the ToC entries and in the headline:

[image]